Flutter App Stuck on "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'" and Not Showing in Emulator
I am facing a significant issue with my Flutter project in Android Studio. When I try to run my app, it gets stuck on "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'..." and takes an exceptionally long time to proceed. Additionally, my Flutter app is not showing up in the emulator. Here is a screenshot of the problem:
I have tried multiple solutions to resolve this issue, including:
Updating Android Studio and all related components.
Increasing the memory allocation for the IDE.
Cleaning the project and rebuilding it.
Deleting and reinstalling the emulator.
Running flutter clean and flutter pub get.
Checking for any inconsistencies or errors in my build.gradle files.
Despite these efforts, the problem persists. I would appreciate any insights or solutions that could help me overcome this hurdle.
Here are some details about my setup:
Android Studio version:  Android Studio (version 2023.3)
Flutter version: Flutter 3.22.1
Operating System: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3593], locale en-MY)
Emulator:Pixel 8 Pro API TiramisuPrivacySandbox Android 14 x86_64
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
Emulator Screenshot
Console screenshot
I have tried all the solutions are given by the experts from multiple source but nothing is working out for me and I expect to run my codes without these errors again and in my emulator its should show the flutter app logo
